# Function not running after calling in LinkList implementation

Tags: java, linked-list

I am having a very awkward and simple doubt. I am implementing Linklist in Java.
and the **Display()** function even after being called is **not printing anything**. The function is in the Linklist class, but when i call the function, nothing happens. Not even the *System.out.println("Display")* line works.

```
//Link class
class Link
{
    String name;
    Link next;
    Link(String name)
      {
        this.name=name;
        next = null;
      }
}
//Linklist class
class Linklist
{
    Link first;
    Linklist()
      {
        first=null;
      }

public void addLinks(String name)
{
    Link search=first;
    if(first==null)
    {
        Link head = new Link(name);
        first=head;
    }
    else
    {

        while(search.next!=null)
        {
        search.next=search;
        }
        Link newlink = new Link(name);
        search.next = newlink;
    }
}
//This function is not working properly.
public void display()
{

    System.out.println("Display");
    Link search=first;

    while(search.next==null)
    {
        System.out.println(search.name);
        search.next=search;
    }
}
}

public class p1 {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Linklist ls = new Linklist();
    ls.addLinks("Kanha");
    ls.addLinks("lal");
    ls.addLinks("Mishra");
    ls.display();
}

}
```

Comment: any exception..?? just try to call ls.display() before adding any node. see if it works..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there is a never ending loop (in both `addLinks()` and `display()` methods), so it never gets the chance to print anything:

```
while(search.next!=null)
{
    search.next=search;
}
```

You probably meant to write

```
search = search.next;
```

Also, the condition of the while-loop in `display()` should instead of

```
while(search.next==null)
```

be

```
search.next != null
```

(but you'll have to print the content of the first element before...)

Comment: @KanhaiyaMishra, no problem. Feel free to accept the answer, so your question doesn't appear Unanswered. (you'll get points!)

Comment: sure, I am new so didnt know that, btw accepted your answer. :)